# Two different authorization schemes in a Rails 3.1 web service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, authorization

I'm creating a web service with Rails 3.1 that requires authenticated user accounts for creating/managing content. It also requires an authorization scheme for transient 'users' accessing the content - they do not have accounts, but will simply provide a password furnished to them by the user who created the content in their requests.

I'm thinking the best strategy is to keep the two separate, not creating accounts for the transient users, representing them as a separate model associated with the content.

My question is whether this is something I should build from scratch, or whether I can get sufficient leverage from one of the existing authentication gems for it. And if the latter, how I would go about configuring it to manage two different strategies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I don't really need an authentication gem. While the implementation isn't finished, it appears a combination of Rails 3.1's has_secure_password and [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) will work well for this.

Here's Ryan Bate's tutorial for using has_secure_password: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1

The idea is to use has_secure_password on both the User and Content models, and implement current_user such that it creates a transient User when the password is provided, setting a password property on that transient user.Then the implementation of the init method in CanCan's Ability class will verify the transient user's password against the content in a can block.

Comment: The uses of an authentication gem provide not only the authentication gears but also views and helpers.
Let's keep ... devise for exemple ... offer views, locales, helpers, mail notification, support for openId etc ...

Answer (score 0):

If understand right, you will have regular account users and temporary account generated by users to share access to whatever.
I don't think something for this specific purpose exist.
My think using a solid and confortable Auth Manager gem will be require to secure both user and tmp_account access.
The reste, ie managing user-tmp_account relation and managing life time + right of the tmp_account, could be done without pain manually.
I personally build up something similar with the gem Devise.

Comment: Users will not explicitly create temporary accounts. Instead, they will furnish passwords to anyone interested in the content, and then those people will access the password-protected content. Sounds convoluted, but it is appropriate for this service.

Comment: With devise : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
You have many option to tell what an account can do or not :

    class MasterUser
        devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, :recoverable

So basically you will have a MasterUser + a SlaveUser models.
The SlaveUser model is created by MasterUser who provides the password.
SlaveUser with restricted devise options cannot edit, restore password.